# Can I have StackExchange sites only load my favorite tags when I visit them?

Tags: feature-request

With the popularity of content curation sites over the past few years I, and I imagine a lot of other users have come to expect functionality behind features like `Favorite` that they will further tailor my browsing experience to match my interests.

With this in mind - when I first land on a StackExchange site is there a way the question tab can default to just displaying my favorite tags when I'm already logged in?

Comment: It's easiest just to change your bookmark to e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20is%3aq

Comment: You can, but it's a huge pain to have to do that when you visit frequently across different devices (long train rides!)... it would be great to have it as a default.

Comment: Don't your bookmarks sync across devices? The iOS app (and probably also the Android app) save your searches, too.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Like many other developers I have a Windows Phone (occupational hazard). I don't think there's a way to sync bookmarks to any of the browsers on there as yet?

Comment: Ah, no, it looks like there isn't!

Comment: You could add every other tag to your ignore list >:)